# Windows Phone Keyboard Back-key press event?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am working on a windows phone application.

I noticed that after I show up a textbox and a keyboard, if I press physical "back" key, the keyboard will hide, and press again it will go back to previous page.

But I want the page to navigate to previous page when the "back" key is press the first time. So its like the keyboard is up, when I press back key, it directly go back to the previous page.

I tried to implement the `BackKeyPressed` event handler of the page but it does not seem work, since it is not called when the first time back key is pressed.

Anyone has any good idea with this? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a KeyUp eventhandler on the inputbox and then detect for Escape key event before calling NavigationService.GoBack(). Here is a piece of code to illustrate my point and the effect you are describing above:

The XAML (SecondPage.xaml):

```
    <TextBox x:Name="SomeTextBox" KeyUp="SomeTextBox_KeyUp"/>
```

The C# Code-behind:

```
    private void SomeTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        {
            NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not working since press back key is not a trigger of the `KeyUp` event. So this is not called when I press the back key. In another word, back key is not part of the keyboard so the keyboard keyup will not be triggered. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: I tried the code and it worked on the emulator. Did you try it out?

Answer (score -2):

you can implement the LostFoucs event handler of theTextBox,navigate to the page which you want in the handler.

Comment: The textbox won't lose focus only when the back key is pressed.  It may *not* lose focus when the back key is pressed, in fact, so this solution isn't likely to work at all.

Comment: No this will not work since if you tap anywhere out side the textbox and keyboard, it will lost focus and return to the previous page.